# Retrieving all records in order of precedence in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have an app that has videos which can be searched for. Some videos are free to watch, while others are premium content. Is it possible to retrieve a list of records like this where the premium content coming first in the list, and the regular coming last:

```
Video1 - Premium
Video3 - Premium
Video4 - Premium
Video2 - Regular
Video5 - Regular
Video6 - Regular
```

The videos are not ordered necessarily by `id` but rather by status, or 'precedence' you could say.
I'm currently handling `premium` and `regular` with an enum called status.

```
enum status: [:regular, :premium]
```

I was wondering if you get such a result with only one query, or would you have to retrieve all the data first, and then just sort it? The former seems more efficient, and that is why I was wondering if you could do that.

Could you maybe use the `.order()` method?

I know that `Video.all.order(:status)` gives an error, but I don't know if you could still use the same query in a slightly different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
Video.order("status = 1, status = 0")
```

premium has a value of 1, regular has a value of 0.

or...

```
Video.order(status: :desc)
```